# How to log custom plugin error to debug.log file

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I was searching google for this on how can log my plugin error's  to debug.log after enabling the  `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` but there is no luck for me, any expert have done this before?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Do you have `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` also? What are you doing to try to log the custom plugin errors to the file?

Answer (score 1):

U need to also define **WP_DEBUG** as **true**

```
 // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

It will may help you.